# Call different events on an element depending on its id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button:

```
<button id="end-action">End action</button>
```

And I am trying to change the text and id of the button in response to a click event.

```
$("#end-action").click(endAction);
$("#end-turn").click(endTurn);
```

When I click on the button, it successfully calls the endAction function (below) and correctly sets the id of the button to "end-turn".  However, when the id of the button is "end-turn", if I click on the button, the "end-action" id event handler is still called.

```
       function endAction(){
    $("#end-action").text("End Turn");
    $("#end-action").attr("id", "end-turn");
       }

       function endTurn(){
    $("#end-turn").text("End Action");
    $("#end-turn").attr("id", "end-action");
       }
```

Do you know why this is and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, why don't you use class ? You won't even have to change ID

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem unfortunately. I could use class, but I think that would have the same problem with the endAction handler being called and the endTurn handler never being called. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function endAction() {
    $("#end-action").text("End Turn");
    $("#end-action").prop("id", "end-turn");
}

function endTurn() {
    $("#end-turn").text("End Action");
    $("#end-turn").prop("id", "end-action");
}
$("body").on('click', '#end-action, #end-turn', function(){
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'end-turn':
            endTurn();
            break;
        case 'end-action':
            endAction();
            break;
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5YDz9/).

The problem, I think, is that you bound an event to the DOM node, after selecting it by its `id`, but that binding happens *once*; and while the `id` might change the DOM node stays the same (despite the `id` property changing) which means that only one function is bound to that node.

The alternative I've used, here, binds the click-handler to the `body` element (though you should bind to the closest ancestor element of the `button`, *not* the `body`, unless you have no alternative), and then assesses which element the `click` event originated on. In this case `this` refers to the event that was clicked, which has its `id` property checked and, if it matches, the relevant function is called.

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 1):

Okay - Is this what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/Fs24R/

```
$("#end-action").click(endAction);


function endAction(){
   $("#end-action").text("End Turn");
   $("#end-action").attr("id", "end-turn");
   $("#end-turn").click(endTurn);
 }


function endTurn(){
  $("#end-turn").text("End Action");
  $("#end-turn").attr("id", "end-action");
  $("#end-action").click(endAction);
```

}

**Explanation:** When you change the id - you have to set the onclick function - because the page is not being loaded again - hence the initial onload function won't run.

When you add the call onload: for second id - it's not present in the DOM at that time - hence the function is not bind to the second id.

Therefore, you have to bind the function at the point where you change the ID of the element.

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes sense why my original solution doesn't work.